# How do I stop my UITabBar from responding to touches after hiding it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

When hiding the tab bar either by:

`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true`

or

`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.zPosition = -1`

The tab bar hides as expected but it still responds to touches and toggles the tab. How do I prevent that from happening?

I want the Tab Bar to appear when the view loads and only hide it during a specific mode then unhide it again so any answers that involve hiding / removing the tab bar prior to load won't help unfortunately.

For some background information, what I am trying to achieve can be thought of as a custom ActionSheet. It comes up from the bottom and I want to utilise the bottom space as much as possible hence hiding the tab bar. The user can then dismiss the action sheet and the tab bar reappears.

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I think the code provided in the question is enough to understand the problem.

Comment: Adding a view over the tab bar that would swallow the taps might help.

Comment: Have you tried setting `.userInteractionEnabled` on the tab bar?

Comment: @Cristik thanks for the suggestion; currently I do have a view over the tab bar already that has buttons but they aren't been fired as the hidden tab bar is still capturing the taps.

Comment: @ThomasRing no I haven't! Thanks I'll try that

Comment: @MichaelHudson have you added the new view as a subview of the tab bar controller's view? If yes, try adding it as a sibling of the tab bar controller view.

Comment: Check enable/Disable property of Tabbar

Answer (score 0):

You can disable with this line of code,

```
self.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to hide and disable the tab bar use this

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

and If you need to hide it on a Push, add like this while you push to a desired VC.

```
let objCreateEventVC = CreateEventVC()
objCreateEventVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(objCreateEventVC, animated: false)
```